# C# Marshal 2 dimensional Arrays

Tags: c#, interop, marshalling

I was wondering if there is any way to marshal a 2 dimensional Array in c#.

For a 1 dimensional Array of length 4, I use

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=4)]
int[] my_array;
```

But what if my Array Looks like this in c: `my_array[2][5]`
Can I put it like

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=2*5)]
int[,] my_array;
```

thank you for your Support :)

Comment: [Doku](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-arrays) - guess you Need to go to LPArray

Comment: I think you can do it if it's an input parameter of your method. If it's an ouput parameter you have to thread it as one dimensional array. Or you could write a custom marshaler.

Comment: The pinvoke marshaller will in effect flatten the 2-dim array to int[10] with my_array[0,0] as its first element, my_array[0,1] as second, ..., my_array[1, 0] as the sixth, etc.  That is what a C compiler does as well.  The only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.